# How to validate an expression in Apache Calcite

Tags: apache-calcite

I want to know how to validate a expression in Calcite. I create a schema and add my table into it, then I want to use Validator to validate a SqlNode which is from an expression. Here is the code.

```
public class DummyTable extends AbstractTable {

    private final String tableName;

    public DummyTable(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }
    @Override
    public RelDataType getRowType(RelDataTypeFactory typeFactory) {
        RelDataTypeFactory.Builder builder = typeFactory.builder();
        builder.add("a", SqlTypeName.BIGINT);
        builder.add("b", SqlTypeName.BIGINT);
        return builder.build();
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }
}
```

```
public class ConditionValidator {
    private final String sql;

    private final SchemaPlus rootSchema;

    private final FrameworkConfig frameworkConfig;

    private final RelDataTypeFactory relDataTypeFactory;

    private final CalciteCatalogReader catalogReader;

    private final SqlOperatorTable sqlOperatorTable;

    private final SqlValidator validator;

    public ConditionValidator(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
        SchemaPlus rootSchema = Frameworks.createRootSchema(true);
        DummyTable testTable = new DummyTable("test_table");
        rootSchema.add(testTable.getTableName(), testTable);
        this.rootSchema = rootSchema;
        this.frameworkConfig =  Frameworks.newConfigBuilder()
                .parserConfig(SqlParser.config()
                        .withLex(Lex.MYSQL)
                        .withConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.DEFAULT))
                .defaultSchema(rootSchema)
                .operatorTable(SqlStdOperatorTable.instance())
                .build();
        this.relDataTypeFactory = new SqlTypeFactoryImpl(RelDataTypeSystem.DEFAULT);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(CalciteConnectionProperty.CASE_SENSITIVE.camelName(), "true");
        this.catalogReader = new CalciteCatalogReader(
                CalciteSchema.from(rootSchema),
                CalciteSchema.from(rootSchema).path(rootSchema.getName()),
                relDataTypeFactory,
                new CalciteConnectionConfigImpl(properties));
        this.sqlOperatorTable = SqlOperatorTables.chain(frameworkConfig.getOperatorTable(), catalogReader);
        this.validator = SqlValidatorUtil.newValidator(sqlOperatorTable, catalogReader, relDataTypeFactory, frameworkConfig.getSqlValidatorConfig());
    }


    public SqlNode validate() {
        SqlParser sqlParser = SqlParser.create(sql, frameworkConfig.getParserConfig());
        SqlNode sqlNode;
        try {
            sqlNode = sqlParser.parseExpression();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        SqlNode validate = validator.validate(sqlNode);
        return validate;
    }
}
```

And now I can validate a SqlNode from a SQL query, for example, when input sql is "select a, b from test_table where a > 1 and b = 1", validation is ok (if validating a query, you should use the way below to parse the sql:

```
sqlNode = sqlParser.parseQuery(); // not 'sqlParser.parseExpression();
```

).

However, when I validate an expression like "a > 1 and b = 1", such an exception occurs: "Column 'a' not found in any table". I assume there maybe something wrong with validate scope, but I can't find the solution. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same error message. I applied the following changes:

Change from:

```
SqlNode validate = validator.validate(sqlNode);
```

To:

```
SqlNode validate = validator.validateParameterizedExpression(sqlNode, nameToTypeMap);;
```

Details:

```
HashMap<String, RexNode> nameToNodeMap = new HashMap<>();
nameToNodeMap.put("a",new RexInputRef(0, relDataTypeFactory.createSqlType(SqlTypeName.BIGINT)));
nameToNodeMap.put("b",new RexInputRef(1, relDataTypeFactory.createSqlType(SqlTypeName.BIGINT)));
final Map<String, RelDataType> nameToTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, RexNode> entry : nameToNodeMap.entrySet()) {
    nameToTypeMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getType());
}
SqlNode validate = validator.validateParameterizedExpression(sqlNode, nameToTypeMap);
```